# Gradle Build fails at generateClientLibs for Cloud Endpoints

Tags: android, gradle, google-cloud-endpoints

We have been using a Generated Client for Google Cloud Endpoints in our Java based Android App for a while now. Unfortunately, it just stopped working today and the Gradle build fails with exception below.

It seems like the Gradle task endpointsClientLib calls a server in generateClientLibs. This server is throwing a 500 Internal Server Error.

We have tried to 
 - upgrade com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin to 2.0.1
 - upgrade com.google.api-client:google-api-client to 1.30.4

But the problem still persists.

Anyway to bypass this problem or run this code generation server locally to see what is causing this Internal Server Error?

Thanks

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:_endpointsClientLibs'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:277)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:135)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:200)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:74)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:143)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:40)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:40)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:24)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:49)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:40)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:33)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ExecuteTasks.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:355)
    ... 77 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 500 Internal Server Error
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:801)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:768)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
    ... 115 more
Caused by: com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 500 Internal Server Error
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1061)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.CloudClientLibGenerator.postRequest(CloudClientLibGenerator.java:65)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.CloudClientLibGenerator.generateClientLib(CloudClientLibGenerator.java:55)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.GenClientLibAction.genClientLib(GenClientLibAction.java:91)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.GenClientLibAction.genClientLibFromFile(GenClientLibAction.java:71)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.GenClientLibAction.execute(GenClientLibAction.java:55)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.EndpointsTool.execute(EndpointsTool.java:84)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.gradle.endpoints.framework.client.task.GenerateClientLibrariesTask.runEndpointsTools(GenerateClientLibrariesTask.java:107)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.gradle.endpoints.framework.client.task.GenerateClientLibrariesTask.generateClientLibs(GenerateClientLibrariesTask.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    ... 47 more
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Very interesting that it happens on the same day. Maybe it's a problem on Google's side.

Comment: same problem for me. It has not been working since 1 hour.

Comment: Seems like a Google problem. Sample project fails as well

Comment: Maybe they changed configurations. Do you manually add your generated client library to the libs directory in you app module?

Comment: @m121212 The generated client library is added automatically using the gradle endpoints plugin in the app module.The problem is with the generation itself.

Comment: @abhideep All right, I was only double checking with you that we are in the same scenario...

Comment: But no solution yet? Is there a way to contact Google about it?

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin/issues/98 I created an issue

Comment: Did anyone find a solution?

Comment: same problem here , org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 500

Comment: Issue occurs here: https://github.com/cloudendpoints/endpoints-java/issues/183. Any chance to solve it? Looks like server processing for get-client-lib changed...

Comment: It seems to be solved now by Google engineers.